# Assigning to a var defined in Protocol says that it can't assign to it

Tags: swift

Here is a simple use case:

```
protocol Debuggable {
    var _d: String -> () {
        get set
    }
}

class Debugger {

    class func attach(instance: Debuggable) {
        let d = Debugger()
        instance._d = d.d // This doesn't work
    }

    func d(message: String) {
        println(message)
    }

}
```

Error message at compile time: Cannot assign to _d in instance, although my protocol defines the var with a getter and setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good case of the compiler catching an error for you :)

`instance` may be a value type and therefore be copied in to this method. In that case, you will modify the copy and just throw it out. The quickest fix is to define it as an `inout` parameter:

```
class func attach(inout instance: Debuggable) {
    let d = Debugger()
    instance._d = d.d
}
```

I think it would be better to return the instance though:

```
class func attach(instance: Debuggable) -> Debuggable {
    let d = Debugger()
    var ret = instance
    ret._d = d.d
    return ret
}
```

I feel that `inout` is mostly in the language for backwards compatibility to Objective-C and C. Let the type determine if it should be copied instead of forcing it to be passed by reference. If something is defined as a value type, there is a good reason for it.

Comment: Wow! I am so unfamiliar with inout. Good catch from you and my friend the compiler.

Comment: Why do you think the latter is better than the former?

Comment: @nhgrif I feel that `inout` is only in the language for backwards compatibility to Objective-C and C. Let the type determine if it should be copied instead of forcing it to be passed by reference. If something is defined as a value type, there is a good reason for it.

Comment: @drewag you are making a very valid point that made me rethink about the whole thing: I am not returning the function from the class func call. Much clearer and less ambiguous.

Comment: I really don't think `inout` is only in the language for backwards compatibility.  Plenty of other languages offer pass-by-reference options, which is essentially what `inout` offers.  The official documentation recommends using `inout` for a simple *swap* function, for example, and there isn't a single reference to "backwards compatibility" or Objective-C in any of the `inout` sections of the documentation.

Comment: And in this case, what do we want to do?  We want to attach a debugger to an already existing instance of an object?  To me, I think the `inout` is more than okay here.

Comment: @nhgrif I agree that it is ok. I just think it is better to avoid `inout` when possible because it isn't clear when calling the function if it is `inout`. This makes reading and understanding the code more difficult. I also don't like the idea of forcing a value object to be passed by reference. However, the swap case is a great example of when it is still useful.

Comment: Isn't clear? IIRC the compiler makes you preface any `inout` argument with `&` at the call site, which I'd call pretty obvious. "Use sparingly" is still good advice though.

Comment: That was so clear until you pointed out the mechanics. I assumed that passing an object of type protocol would pass a ref but it seems that without inout attribute it's passing a copy of the object. May I assume a shallow copy in that case?

Comment: @LorenzoStDubois If it is a Class, it will only copy the reference to it like a pointer. If it is a Struct, it will do a shallow copy yes (which only really applies if your struct has references to classes).